How to run a GQL Query against mock data to get realistic results in unit tests?
I’m looking for a way to run a query against a mock data object.
The problem
I currently mock the GQL response via . That works great, but the mock’s result comes back exactly as defined. The mock response can return fields the query did not ask for.
The request
I would like to have a fake data library and generate the mock result data by getting the fake data and “running” the query against it. Apollo iOS has pretty much what I want 1, but it’s not available for React + Typescript. For example:
const fakeUserData = {id: 1, name: "First Last"};
query = gql`query { user { id } }`;
query.data.from(fakeUserData):
// Returns: {id: 1} without `name`.

Does this exist somewhere? Does this pattern make sense?
Thanks!
The only thing I've found is the iOS client .Data.from(mock), but it doesn't work with TypeScript.

You can write the "too much" data to the store using cache.writeQuery after which you can also query for partial data.
For an example, see the Apollo Client tests themselves
      cache.writeQuery({
        query,
        data: { hello: "from cache" },
      });

